# Trouble loading local modules only with AWS Lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

app structure:

```
.
├── Makefile
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── README.md
├── template.yaml
├── tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── unit
│       └── lambda_application
│           ├── test_handler.py
│           └── test_parent_child_class.py
└── lambda_application
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── first_child_class.py
    ├── lambda_function.py
    ├── second_child_class.py
    ├── requirements.txt
    └── parent_class.py

4 directories, 14 files
```

Code sample from `lambda_function.py`:

```
import os
import json
from hashlib import sha256
import boto3
from requests import Session
from .first_child_class import FirstChildClass


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Do some stuff.
```

As is, I get the error message

> Unable to import module 'lambda_function'

but If I comment out the last import, `from .first_child_class import FirstChildClass`, it is able to get past that part and get the error that I haven't loaded the module for that class.

I only seem to get this error when I run it in the **lambci/lambda:python3.7** docker image and when I deploy on AWS. All my tests pass and it is able to import the module with no problems.

Is there something I should load/setup in the `__init__.py` file?

**EDIT** I changed the names of some of the files to post it here.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are using a `relative import` here which works in case the code you are executing is in a module. However, since your code is being executed not as a module, your AWS Lambda fails.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73149/6391078

A quick run locally gave the following error:

## PYTHON 3.6

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lambda_function.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .first_child_class import FirstChildClass
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.first_child_class'; '__main__' is not a package
```

Your tests pass because your testing suite imports the file as a `module` from the `lambda_application` folder which gets treated as a package in the testing module

---

This got me going in the correct direction but didn't quite give me the answer but did lead me to the answer, so I thought I would update what I found here.

I didn't try it but from what I found, I believe that:

`from first_child_class import FirstChildClass`

would be the simplest resolution.

What I ended up doing was moving the classes into a sub-directory and essentially did the same as above but with a package name prepended.

So, the file structure changed to:

```
.
├── Makefile
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── README.md
├── template.yaml
├── tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── unit
│       └── lambda_application
│           ├── test_handler.py
│           └── test_parent_child_class.py
└── lambda_application
    ├── __init__.py
    └── lib
        ├── first_child_class.py
        ├── second_child_class.py
        └── parent_class.py
    ├── lambda_function.py
    └── requirements.txt
```

and my import became `from lib.first_child_class import FirstChildClass`

Comment: That makes a more sense now. I am just now sure how I need to fix it.

Comment: If the answer solves your problem, please consider marking it as correct answer